# Using reflection to select some properties

Tags: c#, reflection

how to select only some properties of class. let's say I have class

```
public class BaseEntity
{
   protected string _createdBy;
   protected DateTime _createdDate;
   protected string _updatedBy;
   protected DateTime _updatedDate;

   //set get
}

public class User : BaseEntity
{
   private string _username;
   private string _password;
   private Employee _employee;

   //set get 
}
```

I only want to select Username, Password, and Employee, not CreatedBy, CreatedDate, UpdatedBy, and UpdatedDate. Is there any way to do this? I've tried searching by google, but i found nothing
so I can only hardcode it, like this

```
if (!propertyInfo.Name.Equals("CreatedDate") ||
!propertyInfo.Name.Equals("CreatedBy"))
{
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You should use the [BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) flag in your [Type.GetProperties()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx) call, which will ignore inherited properties.